# C# ReportViewer Running on a BackgroundWorker. Exporting/Printing Locks Application up

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, reportviewer

I have set up my reports list, so that it opens a form via a BackgroundWorker:

```
        if (bw_ReportWorker.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // start it
            bw_ReportWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

and in the DoWork() is this:

```
  private void bw_ReportWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        _rl = new ReportList();
        _rl.ShowDialog();
    }
```

the report list comes up, and then you can choose the report you want. When you choose a report, that opens another window appropriate for the report. All the reports show correctly on the screen, but as soon as i try to print or export, the application hangs. 
If i but the Report List without using the BackgorundWorker, i can export and print all i want. 
Why does it hang? and also how to fix this ?
the program is in Winforms with .NET 4.5

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to run a UI operation from a background thread?

Comment: the reason is that all of the reports are accessible no matter what screen the user wants to use. (Leave the report list in the corner of the screen, and use the app normally. when need report, just click the one required in the list without exiting the current screen)

Answer (score 0):

you are running a dialog from a worker thread. this is not a good behavior. this is why the UI hangs. the only thread that should run Dialog, which hangs the opening form by the way, is the UI thread.

if you want to open a form and not hang the form that opens it, use `Show()`